# R Shiny: Use input in inline commands

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I just started to use shiny and I am currently trying to embed widgets in R markdown. I already have a working markdown, and I'm trying to adapt it to a selection box. I followed some tutorials but I think I missed something.

My dataset contains species observations within sites. Here's my code:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
selectInput("region", "Reserve :", 
                    choices=colnames(DF)) #Here i select my site in my dataset DF

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  v <- reactive({ 
           as.character(unique(input$region))})
  })
```
````

Then I have a sentence where I want my site name to apear  inline reactively with the site selection box:

Site name: ``r v`

However, I get "v not found". Seems like I can't access it directly to input$region either.
How can I access to my site name and return it as a character string?

Thanks for your help!